# Como desplegar una app de nextjs 13 en cPanel

Tags: reactjs, cpanel, nextjs, next

Tengo el compromiso de subir una aplicación que esta con NextJS 13 a cPanel. Ya he intentado de todo pero nada me sirve. La documentación de NextJS con respecto a los despliegues en otras plataformas que no sean Vercel es muy lamentable y de verdad necesito ayuda para subir esa aplicación. Aclaro que estoy usando App Router y he tratado de hacer el despliegue agregando el archivo server.js pero esa solución no aplica para nextJS trabajando con App Router sino con Page router. Necesito de su ayuda porque no he podido encontrar información al respecto de como subir una app como esta.

Comment: Estás en la versión 13 ? Te lo pregunto porque de ser así yo me vi hace poco en la misma situación y pude resolverla con una configuración, así puedo colocar mi respuesta completa más abajo.

Comment: Hola, si, version 13 y con App Router. Te lo agradeceria si pudieras colaborarme con una posible solucion gracias

Comment: Hola Santiago, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y elimines toda mención a "urgente", las preguntas de ese tipo no suelen ser bien recibidas, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Si bueno, ya ha sido editada. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr obtener un build utilizando Next.js 13 (digase el tipico HTML, Javascript y CSS) debes agregar a tu archivo `next.config.js` lo siguiente.

```javascript
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  distDir: 'dist',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

La propiedad `output` le dice a Next.js que genere archivos estáticos.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/output

La propiedad `distDir` le dice a Next.js donde debe colocar esos archivos estaticos.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/distDir

Una vez hecho esto ya solo debes de correr el comando `build`

```bash
npm run build
# o
yarn build
```

Si todo sale bien en tu proyecto debes de ver un directorio llamado `dist` lo que esta dentro de este directorio es lo que debes de llevar a tu cPanel.

Comment: Albert muchísimas gracias, ha funcionado. Supongo que será cuestión de esperar a que se no solo sean archivos estáticos sino que se pueda manejar como una aplicación de next como tal. Porque esta forma debe quitar todas las posibilidades y ventajas del SSR ¿Verdad?

Comment: Así es, ya para un app con una API se puede utilizar otras técnicas sin necesidad de tener que utilizar vercel